# Node JS changing output randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

Environment :- NodeJS 14.15.0

In the Following Code :-

```
const sleep_st = (t) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, t));
const sleep_im = () => new Promise((r) => setImmediate(r));

(async () => {
    setImmediate(() => console.log(1));
    console.log(2);
    

    await sleep_st(0);
    
    setImmediate(() => console.log(3));
    console.log(4);

    await sleep_im();
    setImmediate(() => console.log(5));

    console.log(6);

    await 1;

    setImmediate(() => console.log(7));
    console.log(8);
})();
```

Some time the output is :-
2 1 4 3 6 8 5 7

But Sometimes :-
2 4 1 3 6 8 5 7

Comment: It depends on the operating system, CPU usage, ect. It will never be the same for each time.

Comment: What did you expect the output to be and why?

Comment: I expected it, to be 2 1 4 3 6 8 5 7

Comment: Because I was under the impression that SetImmediate Phase runs before Timer Phase